# Giving an html template text using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, templates

I am currently loading an html template into my index.html using:

```
$("#x").load("template.html");
```

and my template file is something like:

```
<html>
  <div id="textBox">
  </div>
</html>
```

Is it possible for me to give the template text from the index.html?

Thanks for your time,
LL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the text from a callback in [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)'s `complete` argument:

```
$("#x").load("template.html", function() {
    $("#textBox").html("Added text");
});
```